# Передача в функцию FILE*

Tags: c, c++

Изучаю язык C

```
int something(FILE* file)
{
    return 0;
}
```

В результате выдается ошибка

> `|23|error: expected ')' before '*' token|`

Как изменить код, чтоб компилятор не выдавал ошибки?

Среда: Code Blocks, компилятор GNU GCC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#include <stdio.h>`?

Comment: Да, все верно. Спасибо